# PostgreSQL what happens if TimeZone is not set?

Tags: postgresql, timezone

From the [docs on 9.1](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html), I see

> If timezone is not specified in postgresql.conf or as a server command-line option, **the server attempts to use the value of the TZ environment variable as the default time zone. If TZ is not defined or is not any of the time zone names known to PostgreSQL, the server attempts to determine the operating system's default time zone by checking the behavior of the C library function localtime(). The default time zone is selected as the closest match among PostgreSQL's known time zones. (These rules are also used to choose the default value of log_timezone, if not specified.)**

This section was however removed subsequently in [9.2](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/datatype-datetime.html), what happens if 9.2+ is *not specified in postgresql.conf or as a server command-line option*?

**My `timezone` currently says `localtime` and I'm wondering what exactly that means and how it's decided.** The original text seems to answer it if it's still applicable. Are we still relying on the `C library function localtime()`?

```
# show timezone;
 TimeZone  
-----------
 localtime
(1 row)
```

I was trying to add this information [in this answer for completeness when I realized that the older docs had more details.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41622590/124486)

Comment: I'm about 95% sure it does the same thing on the server. So I'm not sure why they removed that in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like PostgreSQL 10 still

1. Looks at the environmental variable [TZ first](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/113b0045e20d40f726a0a30e33214455e4f1385e/src/bin/initdb/findtimezone.c#L1385)
2. Proceeds to [use the `localtime` library function](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/113b0045e20d40f726a0a30e33214455e4f1385e/src/bin/initdb/findtimezone.c#L348).
3. Looks under the shared directory or the system directory for [matching timezone information](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/113b0045e20d40f726a0a30e33214455e4f1385e/src/bin/initdb/findtimezone.c#L36).

So it seems like the 9.1 docs are still accurate as of PostgreSQL 10.

Internally, you can see the list of timezone information by using `SELECT * FROM pg_timezone_names();` (here in [the source](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/113b0045e20d40f726a0a30e33214455e4f1385e/src/backend/utils/adt/datetime.c#L4778)) which calls `pg_tzenumerate_start` which the reads the shared directory or system directory above.