# What exactly does 'localtime' mean as value of configuration parameter timezone?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

On PG 9.6, when I do `SHOW timezone;`, I get:

```
 TimeZone  
-----------
localtime
(1 row)
```

which appears also in postgresql.conf as the value of configuration parameter `timezone`:

```
timezone = 'localtime'
```

On PG 9.5, that value used to be my time zone in "full name" format.  Hence my surprise.

I have been unable to find any reference to this value in the documentation.  I suppose it means that PG inherits the timezone of the OS.  But I'd like to be sure, and specially, find where it is documented.

Comment: This might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030175/postgres-at-time-zone-localtime-at-time-zone-utc

Comment: The only part of that answer that seems related is "the server attempts to determine the operating system's default time zone by checking the behavior of the C library function localtime()".  But that has been removed from the documentation in PG 9.5 and 9.6.  I guess they removed that for a reason.

Comment: dupe of this question, https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/160915/2639